# how to select value from a drop down using Selenium IDE

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium, ide

I am using Selenium IDE for the first and has no knowledge of automation scripting. So far i am able to manage using IDE but one issue is I am not able to select a value from drop down list randomly rather entering the index or label values manually every time.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thank You

Answer (score 14):

I tried the below and it worked

Command: Select

Target : element Locator eg : id = card

Value : index=1

Answer (score 1):

Use command `select(selectLocator, optionLocator)`, 'selectLocator' is the Id of the drop down from which the value is being selected and the 'optionLocator' is the value being selected.

For eg: say a drop down having `Id="//select[@id='type'"` with values like 'TypeA, TypeB, TypeC,...'. If you are selecting 'TypeA' from the drop down, your command should go like this:

```
selenium.select("//select[@id='type']", "label=TypeA");
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tried below and it worked.

```
command: waitForNotVisible
target: class=sub-menu
value : index=3
```

Answer (score 1):

General approach is firstly click on the element and then select value from the element.

**For Clicking :** 
1.Command : click
2.target  : element locator like xpath/id/class of the element eg. xpath=xpath of the element

**For Selecting value:** 
1.Command : select
2.target  : same element locator used for clicking
3.Value   : Visible text you want to select / Index  (You will get it by inspecting that element)

Answer (score 0):

First get the total number of items in the dropdown. Use getSelectOptions to get an array of options of the select box. Then generate a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and the length of the array (exclusive. Then use select with an index locator to select the randomly chosen option.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
Command: KeyDown
Target:css=input.comboboxname
Value: \40

\40 is Down-Arrow Ascii value

then use \13 to make selection in value.(put value for command and Target same.)

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty javascript starting point:

```
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()" >click me</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {

   document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length));

}
</script>
```

and the (somewhat) corresponding seleniumIDE runScript command:

command

```
runScript
```

target:

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown").selectedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (document.getElementById("myDropdown").options.length-1))+1);
```

The +1 at the end is entirely optional: I've included it to prevent seleniumIDE from selecting the first

Answer (score 0):

**Command:** Select

**Target:** Search an Element of the website app. (name, id)

**Value:** What value/result do you want to see?

Example:
As an user I want to select a list of colors of drop down list (Orange, Blue, Red) I want to select *Blue* color.
This is a script.

**Command:** Select

**Target:** name=color

**Value:** Blue

Answer (score -2):

It will work with WaitForVisible command

Comment: Please explain how this works. Without some more information, this answer is not very helpful.