# How to test dropdown usign selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to selenium.I am trying to select August month in create gmail account.But my test case is failing.can any help me.

[image]

Comment: Please can you add in the HTML code for your page (the bit for the dropdown at least) and the example of what you have tried on selenum so far. It is difficult to help without seeing either of these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some solutions found here: [how to select value from a drop down using Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213506/how-to-select-value-from-a-drop-down-using-selenium-ide)

But try this snippe that selects "saab" from the drop down based on the "value":

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>//select</td>
    <td>value=saab</td>
</tr>
```